# openocd freertos awareness can't start gdb

Tags: gdb, freertos, gdbserver, openocd

I have a setup with openocd and arm-none-eabi-gdb and I'm trying to debug a FreeRTOS fw.

I start openocd with:

```
openocd -f /usr/local/share/openocd/scripts/board/stm32f0discovery.cfg -c "stm32f0x.cpu configure -rtos auto"
```

That command works fine.

Then I run `arm-none-eabi-gdb -tui` and at the end of my .gdbinit I have:

```
target remote localhost:3333
monitor reset halt
file build/fw.elf
load
continue
focus next
```

But when I try to stop `<ctrl>-c` and start `continue` my fw all I get is the error:

```
Cannot execute this command without a live selected thread.
```

What am I missing?

I'm using a JLink Base debug probe.

Comment: Do you found any solution for this problem? I am facing the same problem, and cannot find any solution

Comment: Looks related to this problem: https://mcuoneclipse.com/2016/10/23/workaround-for-error-in-final-launch-sequence-cannot-execute-this-command-without-a-live-selected-thread/

Answer (score 0):

My case is a bit different than yours, with a setup using QtCreator and its Baremetal plugin, but found a bug report where they state a workaround:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-18436

The workaround is pretty easy:

```
in GDB Init commands add "info threads" after load command. It fixes issue.
```

I tried it, and it worked, the error message was removed, and now I can see the different tasks in FreeRTOS.